# ESP8266 MCU not clearing memory?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am still new at this.
Using Arduino IDE

My MCU was working as a web server with HTML code on SD card using the Webserver sketch. After trying to include other inputs it stopped working with "Timed out waiting for packet header"
Decided to abandon that for a while.

I loaded the standard Blink sketch, repowered MCU, pressed rst and Flash in prescribed sequence. Powered card and checked for compilation - All OK.

Uploaded Blink sketch and  got "esptool FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet error" again. Repeated power down etc. but same. Something seems to be lingering.

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Serial, None, All Flash Contents, 115200"
```

```
C:\Users\IAN\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1/python3 C:\Users\IAN\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0/tools/upload.py --chip esp8266 --port COM10 --baud 115200 erase_flash --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash 0x0 C:\Users\IAN\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_567362/Blink.ino.bin 

esptool.py v3.0

Serial port COM10

Connecting....

Chip is ESP8266EX

Features: WiFi

Crystal is 26MHz

MAC: 3c:71:bf:3b:03:1f

Uploading stub...

Running stub...

Stub running...

Configuring flash size...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\IAN\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module>

    esptool.main(cmdline)

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 3599, in main

    detect_flash_size(esp, args)

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2848, in detect_flash_size

    flash_id = esp.flash_id()

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 688, in flash_id

    return self.run_spiflash_command(SPIFLASH_RDID, b"", 24)

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 948, in run_spiflash_command

    old_spi_usr = self.read_reg(SPI_USR_REG)

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 562, in read_reg

    val, data = self.command(self.ESP_READ_REG, struct.pack('<I', addr))

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 386, in command

    p = self.read()

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 331, in read

    return next(self._slip_reader)

  File "C:/Users/IAN/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2636, in slip_reader

    raise FatalError("Timed out waiting for packet %s" % waiting_for)

esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header

esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Comment: fail after "Stub running..." is unusual. try a different USB cable and port

Comment: Tried rebooting PC and different USB port.
Cable is new and working.
I have already researched for 2 days.

Comment: how is the ESP8266 powered during all this?

Comment: Powered via USB